# why this php substr_replace() doesn't replace the first word

Tags: php, string, strpos

```
<?php 
$offset =0;
if (isset ($_POST['text']) && isset($_POST['searchfor'])&&isset($_POST['replacewith'])) 
{
$text = $_POST['text'];
$search = $_POST['searchfor'];
$replace = $_POST['replacewith'];

$length = strlen($search);

if (!empty($_POST['text'])&& !empty($_POST['searchfor'])&&!empty($_POST['replacewith']))
{
while ($stringpos = strpos($text, $search, $offset)) 
{
$offset = $stringpos + $length;
$text = substr_replace($text, $replace, $stringpos, $length);
}
echo $text;
}
else
{
echo 'Please fill in all the fields';
}

}

?>

<form action=53fineandreplace.php method="POST">
<textarea name = "text" rows="6" cols = "30"></textarea><br><br>
Search For:<br>
<input type= "text" name = "searchfor"><br><br>
Replace with:<br>
<input type="text" name = "replacewith"><br><br>
<input type = "submit" value = "Submit">
</form>
```

If the word to be replaced is the first word or the only word in the string then it doesn't work but if the word to be replaced is in any other position except the first then it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

`strpos` returns the position the needle (`$search`) is found in the haystack (`$text`). If it's found at the beginning of the it, `strpos` will return `0`, which PHP treats as `false`, and thus terminate the `while` loop without even entering it. One way to solve this is to use the `!==` operator to distinguish between a boolean `FALSE` and an integer `0`:

```
while (!($stringpos = strpos($text, $search, $offset)) !== FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below php function `str_replace` and achieve it easily

Syntax

```
str_replace(find,replace,string,count)
```

*find*  -> It is required field.Specifies the value to find

*replace*   -> It is required field.Specifies the value to replace the value in find

*string*    -> It is required field.Specifies the string to be searched

*count* -> It is Optional field.A variable that counts the number of replacements

Answer (score 0):

you should just use the do while loop because it will execute at least once but you need to make the variable in the first if statement just like this

```
if (isset($_POST['text']) && isset($_POST['replace_what']) && isset($_POST['replace_with'])){
  $text=$_POST['text'];
  $search=$_POST['replace_what'];
  $replace=$_POST['replace_with'];
  $string_length=strlen($search);
  $offset=0;
  $strpos=0;
  if (!empty($text) && !empty($search) && !empty($replace)) {


    do{
      $offset= $strpos + $string_length;
      $text=substr_replace($text,$replace,$strpos,$string_length);




    }while ($strpos= strpos($text,$search,$offset));
```